# When generating dat file using postgresql procedure there getting error

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I’m getting super user access privileges err when I’m trying to generate the dat file using  postgresql procedure.

I’m facing one issue in postgresql procedure. Previously I used oracle DB. There I created one procedure for fetching values from table and generate the .dat file using  **UTL_FIlE** In postgresql UTL FILE is not supported that’s why I used **COPY TO** function inside the procedure to write or generate the dat file.  In this case I’m getting super user privileges err.

Comment: Include your code and the exact error you get

Answer (score 0):

Since `COPY TO` writes a file on the database server, you need high permissions: either the user must be a superuser or a member of the `pg_write_server_files` role.

An alternative way to write files would be to create a function in PL/Python or PL/PerlU or another "untrusted" server procedural language. But you need a superuser to create such a function.

Comment: I’m trying to generate a file in different path not a database server. Same thing i’m done in oracle database. There I won’t face any issue. Okey. How can give the super user access or pg_write_server_files.

Comment: That's not what `UTL_FILE` does, as far as I know. It writes a file on the database server.